# Should I use SPF spam protection or DNS blackhole lists for Server-wide mail settings?

Tags: email, spam, spf

It seems that my Server-wide mail settings are preventing some legitimate email from being sent and received.

I have used both SPF spam protection and DNS blackhole lists (zen.spamhaus.org) for several years but lately I've lost a few clients because of persistent email issues.

Here is a screenshot of my current Server-wide mail settings in Plesk:

[image: Screenshot of server-wide mail settings in Plesk]

You can see DomainKeys spam protection and relay options are also set all of which were tweaked years ago to try to limit spamming through the server.

How do my settings look and what would you change?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ten megabytes of message size? Sounds low.

Nothing else to change.

The question remains: What were the mail issues your clients encountered?

Comment: Yes I updated it to 20mb. I also turned off DomainKeys and changed SPF to a lighter setting. Thanks for your input, how do these new setting sound?